# When and how org.neo4j.graphdb and org.neo4j.driver is used?

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

I have been using Neo4j driver for an Java Project.When dealing with nodes i saw that neo4j driver has a Node Class as well as the neo4j grpahdb. Neo4j graphdb's node could do many things including getting the id of a node. I want to know how these Node classes are used.

Answer (score 3):

The [Java core API](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/) (org.neo4j.graphdb) is used when the code runs in the same JVM as Neo4j, which can happen in 2 situations:

- when extending Neo4j, through an [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/#server-unmanaged-extensions) (the usual way until Neo4j 3.0) or a [user-defined procedure](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/#procedures) (since Neo4j 3.0)
- when using [Neo4j embedded](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/#tutorials-java-embedded)

The [driver API](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/drivers/) (org.neo4j.driver) is used when accessing Neo4j remotely, with the Bolt protocol.